# Why does venv contain an older version of pip (9.0.3)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

Why does venv contain an older version of pip (9.0.3). Everytime I have to upgrade using `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`. Is there any alternative to have latest pip when creating the venv?

Comment: `pip` is an external tool whose release schedule is not bound by Python's release schedule. While it isn't found in the standard library, a distribution can choose to include a recent version of `pip` in `site-packages` on installation. That said, what version of Python are you using? Python 3.7 that ships with macOS has `pip-19.0.3` at least (`pip-20.1` is the latest version as of this writing).

Answer (score 1):

When setting up `venv`, [`ensurepip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html#ensurepip.bootstrap) is being used. Depending on your distro, this may be packaged with the interpreter itself or come as part of another package.*)

You can run this oneliner to query your interpreter which version it's using (and hence will be in your new environment):

```
python3 -c 'import ensurepip; print(ensurepip.version())'
```

---

*) In case of Ubuntu 18.04.x which I suspect may be your case. `ensurepip` is part of `python3.6-venv` (version dependent) and it serves `pip` matching `/usr/share/python-wheels/pip-*.whl` as packaged with `python-pip-whl`.

In my case (Slackware) for instance it all comes packaged with the interpreter in `python3-3.8.2-x86_64-1`.